# I got a question about trig on the unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

The unit circle is defined to be $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Makes sense. Its an equation of a circle. Now from here if we think about cosine as the $x$ value and sine as the $y$ value then we get a trig identity most of use know. There was something about this that always bothered me. And maybe this sounds crazy, but why can we use trigonometric functions to define a point on the unit circle?

$$\cos x  = \frac{ \text{adj} }{ \text{hyp} } \quad \text{and} \quad \sin x  = \frac{ \text{opp} }{ \text{hyp} }$$

So I can see why $\cos(x)$ would be defined in terms of an $x$ value since the adjacent side is the leg of the triangle that is on the $x$ axis but where is the hypotenuse going at in this argument? Same for sine.

Sorry I over think things but I like to really know what something is saying.

Comment: The triangle's vertices are at (0,0), (x,0), and (x,y). The hypotenuse is from (0,0) to (x,y), which is just the radius of the circle (i.e. 1). ($\theta$ is measured from the $x$-axis to the point.)

Answer (score 1):

If we see $( \cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ as a point in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then we know that the distance from $(0, 0)$ to $( \sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ is (according to the Pythagorean Theorem)

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(\cos \theta - 0)^{2} + (\sin \theta - 0)^{2}} & = \sqrt{(\cos \theta)^{2} + (\sin \theta)^{2}} \\
& = \sqrt{1} \\
& = 1
\end{align*}

Of course, the definition of a circle with center $(h, k)$ and radius $r$ is the set of points which are a distance $r$ from the center $(h, k)$. We see that every point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ is a distance $1$ from a center $(0, 0)$. That is to say, $(h, k) = (0, 0)$ and $r = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to say this is that the map $\theta \mapsto (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ *parameterizes* the unit circle. (The fact that the image of this map is contained in the unit circle is exactly a consequence of the identity you mention.)

Geometrically, the point corresponding to $\theta$ is the intersection of the unit circle with the ray that makes a (signed) angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis, so that the hypotenuse is the line segment with endpoints this intersection and the origin. (As usual in the setting, we allow *adj* and *opp* to take on negative values according the quadrant in which the indicated ray sits.)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this reference : 
in this please read section 4.14.. This is a very good source of basic trigonometry.
http://gujarat-education.gov.in/textbook/Images/11sem1/maths11-eng/chap4.pdf